# use of "rather" in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, usage

what does "rather" mean here?

> It is part of their job to identify new security phenomena and define
> strategies to cope with them. Therefore they are often trained and,
> thus, predisposed to looking for security questions.
>
> > Rather these
> > questions are important as an indication that the collapse of an
> > institutionalized understanding of the security environment generates
> > a complex game of producing new, legitimate security knowledge.

sorry i don't know how this works but i tried my best to show rather is in the beginning of second paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Rather than" typically has a meaning similar to that of "Instead of". But when "Rather" is used on its own like this, at the beginning of a sentence, the meaning is more like "However". Let me explain (and watch what I do next -- I'll bold the relevant sentence).

Just like, "However", the word "Rather" suggests that what is about to be said is in contrast to some expectation one might get from what has just been said. But unlike "However", "Rather" is not setting up a contrast with what *might* be inferred from the previous text. **Rather, "Rather" is used to indicate that we are about to make a contrast with what almost anyone would take to be implied by the previous text.**

(See what I just did there? )

Another example:

> In most European countries, frogs are not consumed as food, however that is not the case in France. Rather, the French consider frogs legs to be a delicacy.

The only trouble is, that doesn't actually make sense given what is being said. The key part begins:

> Rather, these questions are important ...

(Note my added comma)

What I *think* it is trying to say is something like:

> Now, based on the previous sentence, one would tend to infer that the questions are important for [Reason A]. But that would be incorrect. **Rather, these questions are important [for Reason B]**

But the first part of your text actually fails to set up [Reason A] so that it can then be contrasted later. But for now I'm going to blame the first part, and stick with my parsing of the second part.

(That was surprisingly difficult to explain; I hope it's clear.)

Comment: wow thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

"Rather" means "more preferred" (or "preferrably"), or "very" in some circumstances but at the beginning of the sentence it mostly means "on the contrary", or as exclamation, "certainly" (but that is considered outdated). Can you give the previous sentence, as well, for more context?

EDIT: I believe in this case it would mean "certainly".

EDIT 2: I type as I think, so later on I have to make it more legible. -.-

Comment: This seems like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I did state the meaning of the word, didn't I? In order to give them a better answer, I need more context because a lot of things in English depend on the context.

Comment: yes here it is

>...It is part of their job to identify new security phenomena and define strategies to cope with them. Therefore theyare often trained and, thus, predisposed to looking for security questions.
      Rather these questions are important as an indication that the collapse of an
institutionalized understanding of the security environment generates a complex
game of producing new, legitimate security knowledge....

Comment: But it clearly does not mean "very" here, so I don't think that answer helps the questioner.

Comment: @Kiarash - edit your question, so as to add the sentence there, please.

Comment: @stangdon It's clear for you, but you cannot presume anyone else's level of knowledge or automatically assume they know what you know.